# compiling book template 3 times!

Tags: compiling

I found the [The Legrand Orange Book](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) but it needs to be compiled 3 times in order to see the final output. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: This is only required the first time you compile a document (and only if it includes references from a bibtex database). Next recompilations after small modifications usually require only one or two passes (as long as you don't delete the auxiliar files). You can use `latexmk` tool to automatically run the required number of passes and no more

Comment: it can quite often take more than three times, but unless you write the entire book at one sitting and need to process it without further edits that should not be an a problem.

Comment: If a book has tables of contents at the front that reference pages at the back then it _must_ take multiple passes to resolve all the cross references. Some non-latex systems may seem to only take one command but they will be doing multiple passes internally so that is only a cosmetic difference really.

Comment: What is then the easiest way to compile this template? Should I remove the table of contents until the book is ready? Should I use `latexmk` (which I had no idea about until I read the comment).

Comment: I'd humbly recommend arara for recording and performing the 'from scratch to final' build. After that initial build, single passes should be just fine. It doesn't really matter if you include `\tableofcontents` in your draft or not – just don't rely on it being 'camera-ready' (i.e. this is the final copy; no 'but's about it) until you do the full build.

Comment: @aaragon no there is no need to remove the table of contents, it's just that if you edit and add a new section that section will not be in the toc on the first time you process the document, but that hardly matters as you will almost certainly edit and re-process anyway so the table of contents will be there by the time you need it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is normal (in any system) and unavoidable. You can not complete a table of contents until you know all the pages, similarly page reference, any forward references to sections/ figures etc. So on the first pass these references are not known, on the second pass you can use the values from the earlier pass, but the act of filling in all the references changes the text so some of the references will be incorrect corrected on third (or more) passes. latex warns you if references have changed and that an additional run is required, but while editing it very rarely matters so you just need to process the document once with latex after each editing session.

A system that appears to resolve all forward references in a single command must be doing multiple passes internally, you can of course construct such a command that runs latex multiple times. several have been mentioned in comments eg , latexmk and arara, also: rubber, make, shell script, windows batch files etc, and many tex-aware editors allow setting up a sequence of commands on a single key or menu item.